# How to model reverse recovery diode in LTSpice?

Tags: diodes, ltspice, modeling, reverse-recovery

I wanted to update this subject as LTspice has evolved from this post: [How does LTSpice model reverse recovery time?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/494817/how-does-ltspice-model-reverse-recovery-time)

To sum up the above post answered by Ste Kulov:

As Ste Kulov said, LTspice allows to model reverse recovery time. From the JEDEC document JESD282B.01, the reverse recovery is defined as follow :

[image]

Some definitions of the terms in this image:

\$I_F =\$ The forward current prior to reversal.
\$I_{RM(REC)} =\$ The maximum reverse current peak after reversal.
\$di/dt =\$ The slope of the transition from forward current to reverse current.
\$t_{rrr} =\$ The subscripts imply "reverse recovery rise" time, but this is normally called the storage time.
\$t_{rrf} =\$ The subscripts imply "reverse recovery fall" time, but this is called either transition time or transient time in various texts.
\$t_{rr} =\$ This is what you know as the reverse recovery time as specified in manufacturers' datasheets under certain conditions. It is simply the sum of \$t_{rrf}\$ and \$t_{rrr}\$.

The part which is defined as the "reverse recovery rise" time \$t_{rrr}\$ can be modeled according to the different references given by Ste Kulov: *"The full derivation of this approximation is discussed in the last few pages of [this PDF snip](https://web.archive.org/web/20100629235230/https://www.ece.uic.edu/%7Ei442/Lecture_7_material.pdf) (or [cached screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VejjR.png)), which appears to be an excerpt from [Solid State Electronic Devices by Ben G. Streetman](https://books.google.com/books/about/Solid_State_Electronic_Devices.html?id=egsoAQAAMAAJ).."*  To sum it up:

$$t_{rrr} = TT \cdot \text{ln} \left[ 1 - \frac{I_F}{I_{RM(REC)}} \right]$$

Where \$TT\$ is, according to LTspice, defined as the transit time:

[image]

Nevertheless, the transit time does not model the "reverse recovery fall" \$t_{rrf}\$. At the end of its post Ste Kulov is saying that since LTspiceIV, LTspice allows to model it via the soft reverse recovery parameter \$Vp\$.

[image]

Where the documentation from LTspice gives for \$Vp\$ the following definition:

*The soft reverse recovery parameter, \$Vp\$, adds a dQ/dt damping to diode charge as suggested by K.J. Teng and S. Pan in 'Modified charge-control equation for simulation of diode reverse recovery', Electronics Letters, 15th February 1996 Vol. 32 No. 4.*

Nevertheless, I did not have access to this document, and I am not able to set the "reverse recovery fall" \$t_{rrf}\$ by adjusting the \$Vp\$ parameter.

I searched the NGspice documentation but it seems that NGSpice has no parameter for modelling the "reverse recovery fall".

Does anyone know what the relation is between \$Vp\$ and \$t_{rrf}\$?

Comment: How did you try it? It can be done in the `.model` card, with or without `ako`: https://i.stack.imgur.com/U3E1G.png.

Comment: Hi, Thank you for your comment :) I am not saying that it is not possible to simulate the "reverse recovery fall". For example, if I tested a real diode and I know its "reverse recovery fall" by measuring it, should I try several "Vp" randomly and look at what it is the "reverse recovery fall" of diode model to see if it fits with the diode tested ? It will be more appropriate to know what is the relation between Vp and the "reverse recovery fall", if it is possible

Comment: Oh, I don't think there is. You can make `vp=10` and it will still show something but, it will look hideous. I'd recommend values between `0...0.5` for quasi-realistic plots, otherwise there's no documentation explaining what `vp` does in LTspice. I also don't have access to that document, so I cant say too much, except that I *think* it's a gimmick setting (e.g. GoodEnough®). If you have to match `Tt` exactly then you may even have to adjust it, too, together with `vp`, so that the decaying doesn't exceed its setting (in the example `tt=20n` and with `vp=1` it goes well beyond the limits).

Comment: Ok thank you for your help :) Do you know how the manufacturer of semiconductors does to model a diode for example if there is no explicite relation ? I saw that most of the diodes included by default into LTspice does not have a Vp parameter.

Comment: I may do an other post for this question. There is so many parameters to model a diode into LTspice ... And it is just a diode x)

Comment: The `vp` parameter was not there since the beginning, it was added ...uff, I don't know, up to 10 years ago (?, not sure), it's not even in the `Changelog.txt`. It's certainly not a generic SPICE parameter, so it's very possible that many (read: the overwhelming majority) will not have, and maybe not even know about `vp`. It's easy to add, though, with te `ako` (see the example).

Comment: I agree with you. Thank you for your help :)

Comment: If you google "ngspice vp", one of the top results is a big discussion regarding this Vp parameter, including the equations from the $33 paper along with my (failed) attempts of implementing the equation within ngspice:  https://sourceforge.net/p/ngspice/feature-requests/76/  . You have to scroll down a bit to where I attach the equation images since they got removed from the first post.  Also one of the attachments is the test circuit (diode_rr.cir) I used for my tests.  You should delete or comment out the the `.save` statements so you can more easily plot the diode current in LTspice.

Comment: Thank you for all your documentation :) I will take a look on it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think there is any relation other than an afterthought (some 10 years ago, ±5, more - than +), where Mike added the parameter, possibly as a GoodEnough® setting for tinkering (e.g. a "gimmick"). It's not mentioned in the help and not even in the *Changelog.txt* (of either LTspice IV or XVII). You can make `vp=10` and it will still show something but, it will look hideous. I'd recommend values between `0...0.5` for quasi-realistic plots, otherwise there's no documentation explaining what `vp` does in LTspice. I also don't have access to that document, so I cant say too much. If you have to match `Tt` exactly then you may even have to adjust it, too, together with `vp`, so that the decaying doesn't exceed its setting (in the example `tt=20n` and with `vp=1` it goes well beyond the limits).

[image: two ways of using it]

Comment: ...but if someone else knows better, I'd be glad to correct my views.

Comment: A big discussion along with the equations found in the IEEE paper [can be found here](https://sourceforge.net/p/ngspice/feature-requests/76/). Also, there is more info regarding the differences in `Vp` between LTspiceIV and LTspiceXVII [in this message](https://groups.io/g/LTspice/message/126793) and subsequent messages [in the same topic](https://groups.io/g/LTspice/topic/77407536). Lastly, I just wanted to confirm that there is no direct calculation to map \$t_{rrf}\$ to `Vp`. I concur that it is done empirically by matching bench measurements to simulation results of various `TT` and `Vp`.

Comment: @SteKulov Yes, I remember the thread. How can one not remember when the result of so much discussion ends up with the mysterious parameter in question to become even more mysterious? :-) And the one on sf.net shows that the difference is a simple addition of a derivative. Funny enough, your 1st stab resembles LTspice IV's shapes. Personally, I use the `vp` like this: if it's a fast diode (e.g. `1N4148`) then I use `vp=0.2...0.3`, and it it's a slow diode (e.g. `1N400x`) then I use `vp=0.4...0.5`, no more (the "dip" is affected too much). Empirical FTW.

Comment: Thank you so much for all this documentation :) I will take a look on it !